# Does dataframe.to_csv change the modified time attribute of the file argument?

Tags: pandas

When calling  `DataFrame.to_csv(filepath)`, does it necessarily change the last time modified of the file as obtained by `os.path.getmtime()` on linux on a hard drive filesystem?

Or does it write to the file but the mtime does not change?

Or does it compare the file content to what it's writing?

Comment: it will change the mtime, as you can easily verify